# How do I keep Visual Studio deleting the Deploy directory at the end of MSTest run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium, mstest

I have an MSTest project set up that takes a series of screenshots as part of the process.

Currently it appears to be the case that the `TestResults/Deploy_<computername> 2013-10-10 16_52_16` folder is getting deleted at the end of each test run.

I'd like to keep those screenshots for another part of our workflow AS WELL, if possible I'd like to keep a detailed log of the tests that were run.

When I run locally the Deploy directory gets wiped out.

What options do I have for making sure that these results are saved?

Comment: What property on the `TestContext` are you using to build your path? there is one for results that is not supposed to get deleted

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm trying to use 'TestContext.ResultsDirectory' but while I'm waiting for an answer I've got about six other options to try

Comment: actually it's `TestContext.TestRunResultsDirectory` gets saved. Others don't seem to be.  (actually more accurately, that's the first one I've tried that works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2013/02/23/how-to-preserve-the-test-results-directory.aspx) on the subject, does it solve your specific problem?

It looks like the key is telling the `TestContext` about files you add by calling [AddResultsFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.addresultfile.aspx)

Comment: Ahh YES! per my comment above, I'd also added the `AddResultsFile` option.  It must have been that part that made it finally start working.